# Solver Foundation unsolvable?!

Tags: c#, .net, solver

I´m playing around with Microsoft´s Solver Foundation. I want to solve the addition of 4 Variables which equals 711. For my Problem here, there should everyone sees at minimum one possible solution. But my Code don´t want to work. Here´s my Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Services;
using Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Common;
namespace CSP711Problem
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var solver = SolverContext.GetContext();
            var model = solver.CreateModel();

            Domain values = Domain.IntegerRange(1, 711);
            Decision p1 = new Decision(values, "price1");
            Decision p2 = new Decision(values, "price2");
            Decision p3 = new Decision(values, "price3");
            Decision p4 = new Decision(values, "price4");

            model.AddDecisions(p1, p2, p3, p4);
            var target = 711;
            model.AddConstraint("Add", Model.Equals(target , p1 + p2 + p3 + p4) );
            //model.AddConstraint("Mul", 711 == p1 * p2 * p3 * p4);

            DecisionBinding bindP1 = p1.CreateBinding();
            DecisionBinding bindP2 = p2.CreateBinding();
            DecisionBinding bindP3 = p3.CreateBinding();
            DecisionBinding bindP4 = p4.CreateBinding();

            DecisionBinding[] bindings = new DecisionBinding[] { bindP1, bindP2, bindP3, bindP4 };

            solver.FindAllowedValues(bindings);

            string[] valuesp1 = bindP1.StringFeasibleValues.ToArray();
            string[] valuesp2 = bindP2.StringFeasibleValues.ToArray();
            string[] valuesp3 = bindP3.StringFeasibleValues.ToArray();
            string[] valuesp4 = bindP4.StringFeasibleValues.ToArray();

            Console.WriteLine("Price1: \t{0}", string.Join(", ", valuesp1));
            Console.WriteLine("Price2: \t{0}", string.Join(", ", valuesp2));
            Console.WriteLine("Price3: \t{0}", string.Join(", ", valuesp3));
            Console.WriteLine("Price4: \t{0}", string.Join(", ", valuesp4));
            //var solution = solver.Solve();


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run the Code I get an: 
'Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Common.UnsolvableModelException' occurred in Microsoft.Solver.Foundation.dll

Exception. I´m new at this and dont know how to solve the Problem. Can someone please help me. I think the Problem relies on the Problem Definition.

THANKS!

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, you're trying to solve `a+b+c+d=711`.  Without other formulas, this isn't solvable.  What are you expecting the result to be?

Comment: I think the solution should be something like A=10, B=10, C=10, D=681. Okay then I applied the second Constraint model.AddConstraint("Mul", Model.Equals(target , p1 * p2 * p3 * p4) ); but it´s the same result.

Comment: If the system of equations has an infinite number of solutions, as is the case here, it is considered unsolvable.

Comment: Ok, I tried to add some Constraints but the same Result. How would you solve this Problem?